# Endpoint Routing .net core 3-Multiple Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to migrate from .net core 2.2 routing to endpoint routing in asp.net core 3 with following route in startup

My .net core 2.2 route were

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "AppArea",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{did?}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

.net core 3 route

```
  app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
                {                    
                    routes.MapControllerRoute(
                         name:"default",
                         pattern:"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                    routes.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                        name: "areas",
                        areaName:  "myarea",
                            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{did?}/{action=Index}/{id?}");                
                    routes.MapRazorPages();
                   });
```

My issue is in .net core 2.2 above configuration map multiple areas such as `area1` `area2` etc. but in .net core it only works if i give hard code area name not the dynamic areaname

Comment: Follow the link may help you   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8264

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to not specify any area name, you can use this.

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "areas",
            pattern: "{area}/{controller}/{did?}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: so we cannot use MapAreaControllerRoute for dynamic area name?

Comment: No. By using MapAreaControllerRoute you should provide areaName.